# Send html data & form with ajax & stay on current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send an email the contains html table data as well as the input from the user. This is what the email is displaying at the moment.

`Device - iPad  $14000`

`Your App Will Cost Approximately : $14000`

FromEmail

The input from user is not being displayed for some odd reason, I've changed the function to .click & .form but this sends only the input from the user. I really want both of these things to send.

**here is the html**

```
<div class="total-inner">
    <table class="total-table" id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Device - iPad</td>
                <td>$14000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>

    <hr><br>

    <div class="total-text-wrap">
        <p>Your App Will Cost Approximately  :  $<span class="total">0</span></p>   
    </div>

    <br><hr>
</div>

<div class="form-wrap">
    <form method="post" class="quote-form" action="server.php">
        <span>Company:<input type="text" name="name"></span>
        <span>Email:<input type="text" name="email"></span>

        <br>

        <button class="total-button" id="send-quote" type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
 </div>

 <div class="button-wrap">
    <a href="index1.html">
        <button class="total-button" input-type="submit">RESTART</button>
    </a>
    <button class="total-button" id="quote-advance">GET IN TOUCH</button>
    <button class="total-button">SAVE PDF</button>
 </div>
```

**My Javascript/jquery**

```
  Var   contactNode    = $('#quote-advance'),
        quoteNode      = $('.quote-form'),
        tableData      = [],
        totalData      = [];

 contactNode.click(function(){
            $(".form-wrap").slideDown(750);
            $(function(){
                    totalTableNode.each(function(){
                        tableData.push($(this).html());
                    });

                    totalText.each(function(){
                        totalData.push($(this).html());
                    });
            quoteNode.submit(function(e){   
                $.ajax({
                  type : "POST",
                  url : 'server.php',
                  data : "content=" + tableData + totalData,
                  success: function(data) {
                      alert('Email Sent');// alert the data from the server
                  },
                  error : function() {
                  }

            });
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    });
```

**and the php**

```
<?php 
$to  = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Testing';
$message = $_REQUEST['content'];
$message .= 'From' . $_POST["name"];
$message .= 'Email' . $_POST["email"];
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

To reiterate, the email that I'm receiving at the moment contains ONLY the html table data. & if i change the quoteNode function to .click or .form. The email sends the input data, but not the html table data & redirects to blank server.php file (I want it to alert & stay on the current page as well as send the user input & the html table data).
Please help! I'm stumped!!! Cheers!

Comment: First use the browser debugger tools and check if the XHR request to your server contains the data you expect to be sent. I assume, that the data is not part of the request because the "each" function can work asynchronously within the encapsulated function. That means your submit may be triggered BEFORE the data is acutally inserted.

Comment: Ive tried moving the functions around but still I can't seem to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the data isnt filled correctly. It could be submitted before it filled. Can you try this:

EDIT (works at my server):

### HTML/ JS

```
<div class="total-inner">
    <table class="total-table" id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Device - iPad</td>
                <td>$14000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>

    <hr><br>

    <div class="total-text-wrap">
        <p>Your App Will Cost Approximately  :  $<span class="total">0</span></p>   
    </div>

    <br><hr>
</div>

<div class="form-wrap">
    <form method="post" class="quote-form" action="#">
        <span>Company:<input id="name" type="text" name="name"></span>
        <span>Email:<input id="email" type="text" name="email"></span>

        <br>

        <input class="total-button" id="send-quote" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
 </div>

 <div class="button-wrap">
    <a href="index1.html">
        <button class="total-button" input-type="submit">RESTART</button>
    </a>
    <button class="total-button" id="quote-advance">GET IN TOUCH</button>
    <button class="total-button">SAVE PDF</button>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>    
 <script>
var contactNode    = $('#quote-advance'),
        quoteNode      = $('.quote-form');



quoteNode.submit(function( event ) { 
  $(".form-wrap").slideDown(750);

var dataTable = "";

$('.total-table td').each(function() {
    dataTable += $(this).html();    
});

var name =$("#name").val(); 
var email = $("#email").val();
data= 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&content=' + dataTable ;        
  alert(dataTable);
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : 'server.php',
      data : data,
      success: function(data) {
          alert('Email Sent');// alert the data from the server
      },
      error : function() {
      }
    });
event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

### PHP

```
<?php 
$to  = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Testing';
$message = $_POST['content'];
$message .= 'From' . $_POST["name"];
$message .= 'Email' . $_POST["email"];
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: the page still loads server.php & only the email & name is sent =[

Comment: Try out the edit ;)  The data wasn't send corerectly and you dont set an action attribute when you want to use AJAX, also when you declare a variable, you have to write it without capital --> like var

Comment: YOU SIR ARE A KING! THANK YOU SO MUCH. this has stumped me for the past two days... & its one of the final steps to getting this project completed! Thank you so much.

Comment: I've got another issue, when I add additional data to the table. It send the email multiple times?? =\

Comment: Does the alert also trigger multiple times?

Comment: yeah! It does! I'm sure that there isn't much that needs to be changed.. But its really stumped me.

Comment: also the first email contains the first tr of data & the second one contains all of the data. It's going through the table much like an array

Comment: My code creates the table as the user goes through answering each question, javascript appends a <tr><td> "Data" </td></tr> to a table which displays at the end of the script. But the table structure is just the same as the code above. Just created dynamically via javascript

Comment: In all there are 9 <tr><td> "Data </td></tr> created by javascript.

Comment: Can you update your code, to the new one you have now, then i can simulate your problem, maby it's in your javascript which add to the table.

Comment: [myCode](http://codepen.io/Mctowlie/pen/viJyw) this has all of my code on it! Besides the php. I think this might be better than editing my code! Thanks again man

Comment: please note the sending function has been commented out

Comment: I had a look on your code, I couldn't test it but i think the problem is that you dont listen if your form get submitted before sending data.  Can you try to change        <button class="total-button" id="send-quote">SEND</button> in <input type="submit" id="send-quote" value="SEND">

Comment: just tested, still sends through multiple emails

Comment: Received your e-mail ;)